# Is the following result about congruences of lines classical?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

The following result must be classical; I am looking for a reference or an easy proof (I have a rather sophisticated argument).

Let $\mathbb{G}$ be the Grassmannian of lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$, and let $S$ be the complete intersection of two general hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{G}$, of fixed degrees $>1$. Then $S$ parametrizes a 2-dimensional family of lines (a *congruence* in classical language). The claim is that through any point of $\mathbb{P}^3$ pass only finitely many such lines (in classical language again, the fundamental locus is empty).

Answer (score 5):

Let $V = \mathbb{C}^4$ and let $a \in V$. The set of $\mathbb{C}^2 \subset V$ which passes through $a$ is a $\mathbb{P}^2$ linearly embedded in $G(2,V) \subset \mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V)$. The Grassmannian $G(2,4) \subset \mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V)$ is identified with a quadric and the $\mathbb{P}^2$ described above is a maximal isotropic subspace of $\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V)$ for the corresponding quadratic form. When $a$ varies in $\mathbb{P}^3$, we get a $3$-dimensional family of isotropic subspaces of $ \mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V)$. This family is identified with the spinor variety of isotropic $\mathbb{C}^3 \subset \bigwedge^2 V$. The spinor variety is in this case isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^3$, but for reading convenience, we denote it by $\mathrm{Spin}^{3}$.

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be the taulogical bundle of  $\mathrm{Spin}^{3}$. We consider $ p :X = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{R}) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Spin}^3$. By the Borel-Bott-Weyl Theorem, we have an identification (to check?) :

$$ H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_{X/\mathrm{Spin}^3}(d)) = H^0(\mathrm{Spin^3}, S^d \mathcal{R}^*) = S^d (\bigwedge^2 V)^* =  H^0(\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V), \mathcal{O}(d)).$$

We deduce that a pair of general hypersurfaces of degree $d$ and $e$ in $\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V)$ can be seen as a generic section of $S^d \mathcal{R}^* \oplus S^e \mathcal{R}^*$ on $\mathrm{Spin}^3$ and can be also seen as a generic section of $\mathcal{O}_{X/\mathrm{Spin}^3}(d) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{X/\mathrm{Spin}^3}(e)$.

Your statement can now be reformulated as follows :

> **Statement:** Let $d,e \geq 2$ and $f \in H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_{X/\mathrm{Spin}^3}(d)  \oplus \mathcal{O}_{X/\mathrm{Spin}^3}(e))$ be a general section. For all $u \in \mathrm{Spin}^{3}$, the scheme $\{f = 0\} \cap p^{-1}(u)$ is of codimension $2$ in $p^{-1}(u)$.

This is looks very like a Bertini-type result. In that direction, one can prove the following :

> **Lemma 1** : Let $e \geq 2$ and general $h \in H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_{X/\mathrm{Spinor}_3}(e))$. Then, for all $u \in \mathrm{Spin}^{3}$, the scheme $\{h = 0\} \cap p^{-1}(u)$ is of pure codimension $1$ in $p^{-1}(u)$.
>
> **proof:** the section $h$ induces a section a generic section of $S^e \mathcal{R}^*$. The vanishing locus of this section corresponds to the variety of isotropic $\mathbb{P}^2 \subset \mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V)$ which are included in the hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V)$ corresponding to $h$. 
>    We only have to check that the vanishing locus of this section is empty. We have $\dim S^e \mathcal{R}^* = \binom{e-1+3}{e}> \dim \mathrm{Spin}^{3}$ when $e \geq 2$. Furthermore, the vector bundle $\mathcal{R}^*$ is globally generated, we deduce that the vanishing locus of $h$ is empty.
>
> **Lemma 2** [see [here](http://www.math.ens.fr/~benoist/articles/Bertiniplusresume.pdf), the idea is due to Zak] Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ be an equidimensional scheme of dimension $n$. Denote by $\mathcal{H}_{N,e}$ the projective space of hypersurfaces of degree $e$ in $\mathbb{P}^N$. Then, the set of points in $\mathcal{H}_e$ which contains an irreducible component of $X$ is of codimension at least $\binom{e+n}{e}$.
>
> **proof :** [see [here](http://www.math.ens.fr/~benoist/articles/Bertiniplusresume.pdf)].

Using Lemma $1$ and $2$, one proves the following:

> **proposition :** Let $e \geq 2$, $d \geq 3$ and $(g,h) \in H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_{X/\mathrm{Spin}^3}(d)  \oplus \mathcal{O}_{X/\mathrm{Spin}^3}(e))$ be a general section. For all $u \in \mathrm{Spin}^{3}$, the scheme $\{(g,h) = 0\} \cap p^{-1}(u)$ is of codimension $2$ in $p^{-1}(u)$.
>
> **proof :** Denote by $X_h$ the vanishing locus of $h$ in $X$. By Lemma $1$, we know that all the fibers of the map:
>   $$ p_h : X_h \longrightarrow \mathrm{Spin}^3$$
>   are of pure dimension $1$. Let $\mathcal{H}_{\bigwedge^2V,d}$ be the projective spaces of hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 V)$. Denote by $J \subset \mathcal{H}_{\bigwedge^2V,d} \times S$ the subvariety defined by:
>   $$ J = \{(H,s) \in \mathcal{H}_{\bigwedge^2V,d} \times S, H \ \textrm{contains an irreducible component of} \ p_h^{-1}(s) \}$$
>   By Lemma $2$, we know that each fiber of $q : J \longrightarrow S$ has codimension at least $\binom{d+1}{d}$ in $\mathcal{H}_{\bigwedge^2V,d}$. As a consequence, the codimension of $J$ in $S \times \mathcal{H}_{\bigwedge^2V,d}$ is at least $\binom{d+1}{d}$.
>   Since $\dim S = 3$, we get that $\mathrm{codim}(J) - \dim S - 1 \geq 0$ for $d \geq 3$. Hence, the map $p : J \longrightarrow \mathcal{H}_{\bigwedge^2V,d}$ can't be dominant.
>   We deduce that for generic $g \in \mathcal{H}_{\bigwedge^2V,d}$, the scheme $\{(g,h) = 0\} \cap p^{-1}(s)$ has dimension $0$ in $p^{-1}(s)$, for all $s \in S$.

Comment: Thanks very much, though I would not call this an easy proof -- mine is about at the same level of difficulty (but completely different). This, and some other answers of experts, convinces me that indeed an easy proof probably doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm confused about the role of “generic” above. If that’s all one wants, then wasn’t it already well known to Kummer ([1866, p. 1](//archive.org/stream/abhandlungenderk1866deut#page/n384)): *In einem jeden algebraischen Strahlensysteme geht durch jeden beliebigen Punkt des Raumes eine endliche bestimmte Anzahl von Strahlen; diese soll die **Ordnung** des Strahlensystems bestimmen... Diejenigen Punkte, durch welche nicht $n$ bestimmte, sondern unendlich viele ... Strahlen eines Systems $n$ter Ordnung hindurchgehen, sollen **singuläre Punkte des Strahlensystems** genannt werden*. @abx

Comment: @Francois Ziegler: No, it was not known to Kummer. In the text you quote there is nothing which says that "Singuläre Punkte" does not exist under certain conditions. For a good reason: it is false without the assumption on the degrees, which does not appear at all in Kummer's text. For instance a congruence of bidegree $(1,2)$ admits always 16 fundamental points.

Comment: @abx : with pleasure. I am not completely sure about what you call an "easy proof", but half of my answer is about reformulating your statement in modern language. The other half is a combination of fairly elementary results in projective geometry. But of course, it's not a 2-lines proof.

You say your argument is very different and I am very interested to know how it works. Could you tell me the main lines of your argument?

Comment: @Libli: This is a consequene of a more general result: let $E$ be a rank 2, globally generated vector bundle with $h^0(E)\geq 4$ on a smooth projective surface $S$; assume that the Néron-Severi group of $S$ is generated by $\det(E)$. Then $E$ is ample. This applies in particular to a complete intersection surface in $\mathbb{G}(2,4)$, taking for $E$ the restriction of the universal quotient bundle: the Noether theorem insures that $\operatorname{Pic}(S) $ is generated by $\det(E)$.

Comment: @abx : thanks. This is a nice proof! But it seems to me it is more sophisticated than mine :) (Noether Theorem, caracterisation of rank $2$ ample vector bundle on surfaces with $NS = \mathbb{Z}$). Certainly depends on the point of view of the reader...